# Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Howl'

Tags: angular

I have used howler package in my application. I installed the typings using
`npm install --save @types/howler` and in my **index.html** I have included the following script tag

`<script src="./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.min.js"></script>`

But still it shows the error `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Howl'` when I try to serve my application using **ng serve** command.

Comment: You probably need to add it to your app.module.ts in the imports. Just a guess, but most things need to be put in there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install howler and typescript definition:

```
npm install howler --save
npm install @types/howler --save
```

You don't need to import it into your index.html file, just import `howler` directly in your component class:

```
import { Howl } from 'howler';
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, if you have a library which **does not have [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to import**, you just need to [declare the variable](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/) with the declare keyword.

For example, leave your script in your index.html:

```
<script src="./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.min.js"></script>
```

But then in your component (if you are certain that this script will be loaded), you can declare Howl:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var Howl; <-- declare above @Component

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
}
```

Note: You normally see this with Jquery: `declare var $;`

---

Found good source for others facing this same issue:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/why-typescript.html

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped